# Using TypeScript with Dojo - import/export issues

Tags: import, typescript, dojo, export

In the company I work for we are using Dojo framework and lately I have started pushing to use it with TypeScript.
I took a look around and found this great article on how this topic, you can find it here: 
https://gregwiechec.com/2016/01/creating-dojo-widget-in-typescript/

The last 2 lines in this solution are:

```
var exp = _declare("alloy.editors.StringListTs", [_Widget, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin, _CssStateMixin, _ValueRequiredMixin], new StringList());

export = exp;
```

I followed the same pattern and it works great, except for 2 issues that I cant seem to have a good solid solution:
1. If you look at the solution, when calling dojo declare method, the class created needs to be instantiated (this is because dojo looks at properties and not prototype).
2. The more problematic issue, is the fact that I am exporting out the dojo declared object, and not the class it self. This is problematic when you try to import the class (typescript import), and even if I declare the variable exp as the class type, I get an error saying that there is no constructor to what i am trying to import.

Answer (score 2):

I faced your same problem, and for me has been a transpiler issue.

**TL;DR** if you import something using the `import * as WidgetName from '<path>'` syntax and don't use `WidgetName` in the js (like you would do for a widget in a template), the transpiler won't import it. Use `import '<path>'` instead.

---

**Long answer:** It's my first time with TypeScript and, similarly you, I'm converting a dojo project to TypeScript. Hoping to help more people, I'll put few steps which helped me to import modules correctly.

**Step 0** dojoConfig packages

Defining you own package on dojoConfig won't work, modules must be referenced using relative path.

To be clear, with this example:

```
dojoConfig = {
    ...
    packages : [ { name : "myproject",    location : "js/myproject" },
                 { name : "dojo",  location : dojoBase+"dojo"   }, 
                 { name : "dijit", location : dojoBase+"dijit" },
                 { name : "dojox", location : dojoBase+"dojox"  } ]
};
```

It's not possible to have widget importing each other with `import * as WidgetName from 'myproject/WidgetName'` approach, but rather you have to `import * as WidgetName from './WidgetName'` (notice the '.' vs 'myproject').

**Step 1**: importing dojo declaration (not mandatory, as far as I noticed)

I'm relying on node, I pulled *dojo-typing* using `npm install dojo-typings --save-dev`. In the `files` property I specified `[ "src/js/**/*.ts", "src/js/**/*.js", "node_modules/dojo-typings/dojo/1.11/index.d.ts", "node_modules/dojo-typings/dojo/1.11/modules.d.ts", "node_modules/dojo-typings/dijit/1.11/index.d.ts", "node_modules/dojo-typings/dijit/1.11/modules.d.ts" ]`.

**Step 2**: using the correct options on the transpiler:

```
{
    "target": "es5",
    "allowJs": true,
    "module": "amd",
    "moduleResolution": "classic",
    "noImplicitUseStrict" : true
},
```

`noImplicitUseStrict` solved the error *dojo/parser::parse() error TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them*. `allowJs` allowed me to mix TypeScript and native dojo together.

**Step 3**: returning using export

This is an example of a very minimal module which doesn't require/import anything, but only exports a `log` method (file would be 'toast.ts'):

```
const log  = function(message) { 
    window['dojo'].publish("mainTopic",
            [{
                message: "<span style='font-size: 12px;'>" + message +"</span>",
                type: 'info',
                duration: 3000
            }]
        );
}

export { log }
```

For completeness, in pure Dojo you would have written something like (file would be 'toast.js'):

```
define([ ],

        function(){

    var log = function(message) {
        dojo.publish("mainTopic",
                [{
                    message: "<span style='font-size: 12px;'>" + message +"</span>",
                    type: 'info',
                    duration: 3000
                }]
            );
    };

    return { log : log };

});
```

**Step 4**: rewrite your widget and import it correctly

I use a Main widget which takes all the body, here the content of Main.ts:

```
/// <amd-dependency path="dojo/text!./Main.html" name="template" />
declare var template: string;

import * as _Widget from 'dijit/_Widget';
import * as _TemplatedMixin from 'dijit/_TemplatedMixin';
import * as _WidgetsInTemplateMixin from 'dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin';
import * as dojoDeclare from 'dojo/_base/declare';

import './MyVanillaJavascriptWidget';
import './MyModule';
import 'dojox/widget/Toaster';

import toast = require('./utility/toast');

export default dojoDeclare("mm.Main", [ _Widget, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin ], {
    templateString : template,
});
```

There are different types of imports:

1. the first is the one I struggled the most, for the template
2. `import * as ...` is a sequence of dojo objects I use in the class
3. `import '<path>'` is used for widget I declared in the template using data-dojo-type
4. `import name = require('<path>')` is another way to require modules

For completeness, this would be the original Main.js file:

```
define([ "dijit/_Widget", "dijit/_TemplatedMixin", "dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin",
         "dojo/_base/declare", "dojo/text!./Main.html",
         "dojox/widget/Toaster", "./MyVanillaJavascriptWidget", "./MyModule"
         ],

    function(   _Widget, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin, declare, mainTemplate, toast) {

    return declare("mm.Main", [ _Widget, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin ], {

        templateString : mainTemplate,

    });

});
```

**Conclusion**: The missing constructor most probably comes from the way you import a module, checking the transpiled code helped me to understand where the issue was. To succeed with the import, a bit of accuracy is needed here and there (all the steps above should give an overview).

---

I'm still in the process of converting my project (other issues may come out), but I hope this helps also other poor souls trying to use TypeScript with Dojo!